# Real "object-functions" only in header files?

Tags: c++, function, oop, object, static

First let me say I'm coming from Java.

So I dug in C++ OO programming yesterday and I'm a bit confused about the functions in the header file.

To me it seems, the object is defined there, as well as all the functions which only belong to the object, not the static class.
But since I'm used to initialize an object which many fields and then call functions which use those fields to do things and avoid static functions as much as possible, the result is a totally spammed header file, making a .cpp representation of the class almost superfluous.
Do I miss something here or is C++ OOP really just about data objects?

As far as I could find out, cpp files should indeed be used but in its functions everything needed should be handed over via parameters, even the objects of the same class.

Comment: If you don't won't to put functions (of any kind) in a header file, then don't put them there. It's not compulsory.

Comment: Just my humble conclusion. 

@john so there is a way to put those functions in the cpp file?
May you elaborate on that? Could not find a decent resource on that (Even tho Im sure if it is the case, there must be).

Comment: In general Java programmers coming to C++ struggle because they try to apply concepts that work in Java to C++. They are actually **radically** different languages despite the similarity in syntax. You probably need a good book.

Comment: @pikkuez You are talking about class functions (aka methods)?

Comment: I agree, a guiding book.
Yes.

Comment: @pikkuez I'll write up a simple example. Also note that there's nothing stopping you putting the whole class in a cpp file. Header files and cpp files are artefacts of the c++ build system, they have nothing to do with objects or classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two alternatives for defining class methods, the first is within a header file, the second is split between a header file and a cpp file.

```
// *** in the header file only ***
class X
{
    void some_function() { /* some code */ }
};

// *** split between the header file and a cpp file ***

// header file
class X
{
    void some_function(); // declaration only
};

// cpp file
#include "header_file.h"

void X::some_function() // definition
{
    /* some code */
}
```

Comment: Ah now I see, exactely what I was looking for, appreciate this very much, thank you for taking the time!
I was just thinking fields are generally not accessible in a .cpp class if not static as well.